# arraylist of custom object obtained from tostring representation

Tags: java, string, arraylist, tostring

I'm storing an Arraylist of a custom class BetDisplayer, its toString format looks like this :

`[BetDisplayer{user='tester@tester.com', id='p3ojqbes4vletb5i0sc2drq77d', stake=70, returns=252, status='won', actualselections={9=X}, userselections={9=X}, selections='(9/X)'}, BetDisplayer{user='tester@tester.com', id='48207hoos47vmlq57oelbfl03q', stake=500, returns=1800, status='won', actualselections={9=X}, userselections={9=X}, selections='(9/X)'}, BetDisplayer{user='tester@tester.com', id='v2jbr5bj6n42eab3iqdlt1l6ie', stake=580, returns=2088, status='won', actualselections={9=X}, userselections={9=X}, selections='(9/X)'}`

I'm trying to recover the arraylist from its toString representation however I am not sure how to approach it with this format.

Comment: Don't use `toString` for serializaion/deserialization. That is not its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to create a custom algorythm to load them from a string that will be hard to express and also it may be faulty. To be on the safe side i would recomend either trying your luck with Yaml configuration files or Json, they both have pros and cons and there are pleny of libraries out there for them like Gson for Json and snakeyaml for Yaml.

Good luck :- )

Comment: Or just use object serialization (possibly with base-64 encoding if the storage medium requires text).

Comment: @TedHopp i think the op wants a human-readable way to save the objects and thats why they look for String serialisation probably even to allow changes to be done. :- )

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to store this as a shared preference, but I'm having trouble doing that as when I use a Gson to store the Arraylist and then load it up again, I get an empty arraylist as the response. I'm already storing several strings in the shared preferences which work fine so I think it's easier if I do it this way

Comment: @mankee As far as i know you cant store the entire list by json so u have to extract the objects from it and store them seperately, it is not impossible. Have you tried with Yaml?